# Crash in custom cell when leaving and re entering app

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, swift4

I have a weird crash which I cannot solve. I have a tableview which displays data which works just fine. When I leave the app and re enter it (without killing it) it sometimes (really seldom, like in 5% of the cases) my app crashes with the following log

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  App                           0x33c38     PostTableViewCell.configureCellPost(post:) + 125 (PostTableViewCell.swift:125)
1  App                           0x11be48 OverviewVC.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) +     109 (extensions.swift:109)
2  App                           0x11e65c @objc OverviewVC.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 4370343516
3  UIKitCore                      0x2867bc -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 1012
4  UIKitCore                      0x28ea50 -[UITableView _prefetchCellAtGlobalRow:aboveVisibleRange:] + 296
5  UIKitCore                      0x1d755c __48-[UITableView _configureCellPrefetchingHandlers]_block_invoke + 60
6  UIKitCore                      0x180460 -[_UITableViewPrefetchContext updateVisibleIndexRange:withContentOffset:] + 2568
7  UIKitCore                      0x455444 -[UITableView _updateCycleIdleUntil:] + 192
8  UIKitCore                      0x18e2a4 ___UIUpdateCycleNotifyIdle_block_invoke + 644
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1e6c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x11f48 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x11b98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
13 CoreFoundation                 0x51800 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
14 CoreFoundation                 0xb704 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
16 GraphicsServices               0x1374 GSEventRunModal + 164
17 UIKitCore                      0x514b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
18 UIKitCore                      0x296090 UIApplicationMain + 364
19 App                           0xaebc main + 20 (UploadService.swift:20)
20 ???                            0x1055bdda4 (Fehlt)
```

I checked all lines (UplaodService line 20 where is no code and the post cell where at the indicated row there is no code, just a blank line)

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: The crash happens at `PostTableViewCell.swift:125`. So inspect that code. If you can't understand the crash, you need to post the code of that function so we can try to find the error.

Comment: Could you add code block? Also, you can use debugger. Add debug point to cell after put background app, then when you get foreground app you can catch debug point and check what's going on there.

Comment: @DarkDust as I mentioned the code where it crashes is a blank line without code. I can't reproduce the crash but it happens on my clients phones

Comment: Regarding the blank line: are you comparing the correct source code version vs. app version ran by the client? Still, without any code, we will not be able to help you. Your question as-is basically says: _"My app crashes. That's all the information I can give you. Why?"_